# Is there a way to filter a list like a pivot?

Tags: hibernate, java-8

From the database I am getting below list

```
Id FirstName LastName Certificates
----------------------------------
1     A          B    Cert1  
1     A          B    Cert2  
2     C          D    Cert3
```

I want to display the records like

```
1     A          B    Cert1, Cert2  
2     C          D    Cert3
```

Is there any way in java 8 or hibernate so I can get my desired result?

I know using loops and logic, but is there any method for it like *Listagg* function in oracle?

Comment: Why do you call this operation “filter”?

Answer (score 2):

You can use java 8 or hibernate. This is for java 8.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(
            new Item("1", "A", "B", "Cert1"),
            new Item("1", "A", "B", "Cert2"),
            new Item("2", "C", "D", "Cert3")
    );

    Map<String, List<Item>> groupByKey = items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::groupKey));

    List<String> result = groupByKey.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().map(Item::d).collect(Collectors.joining(",")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static class Item {
    String a;
    String b;
    String c;
    String d;

    public Item(String a, String b, String c, String d) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }

    String d() {
        return d;
    }

    String groupKey() {
        return a + "-" + b + "-" + c;
    }
}
```

---

```
Result : 
Cert3
Cert1,Cert2
```

Comment: Instead of collecting into a `List<Item>` which you are going to join into a `String` anyway, you can just collect into a `Map<String, String>` in the first place: `Map<String, String> groupByKey = items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::groupKey), Collectors.joining(","));` Then, when you want to process the values of a map only, you can use `values()` in the first place, instead of using `entrySet()` and calling `entry.getValue()` for each entry. And if all you’re doing is printing, you can do that directly on the map: `groupByKey.values().forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: Is there any way without using Item Class? I will get List<map> from framework

Comment: I used pojo to help me. What do you have in map?